# pygame.error: The video driver did not add any displays

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to get Pygame running on my Mac OS Monterey.  The library installs fine and ends up where it should be.  I've written a number of functioning programs with Pygame on my Linux machine and am using them as tests.  The problem from what I can gather is that pygame.display can't be initialized for some reason.  Every time I run a Pygame program it fails on the call to pygame.display.set_mode().

I am primarily using a wack-a-mole clone for testing.  Here is the error I get:

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.8.2) Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html 
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "mole_attack.py", line 34, in <module>
    WINDOWSURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32) 
pygame.error: The video driver did not add any displays
```

Please let me know if anyone needs more info. I tried to be as detailed as possible.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try the most recent pygame version, or try without passing an explicit depth argument.

Comment: @Starbuck5 I am using pygame 2.1.0 and I'm pretty sure that that is the most recent version.  I tried your suggestion and removed the depth argument but I got the same error.  Anyway any more ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the latest version of Pygame was 2.1.2 and I was using 2.1.0 which I thought was the latest.  I updated Pygame and everything worked fine.  I couldn’t find anything definitive on what changed between these versions and why this error existed to begin with.  I’ll keep looking and see what I can find out.